# PHP: Reduce the Array dimensions in JSON format

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.XML");
$amount = array();
$temp = 0;

echo $xml->getName() . "</br>";

foreach ($xml->RECORD as $first_gen) {
    foreach ($first_gen->Inventory_Value_at_Cost as $second_gen){
        $temp = $second_gen;
        $amount[] = $temp;
    }
}
echo json_encode($amount, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Output

> {"0":{"0":"34954.68"},"1":{"0":"20544.20"},"2":{"0":"102702.76"},"3":{"0":"89018.95"},"4":{"0":"42479.36"},"5":{"0":"58479.60"},"6":{"0":"47609.10"},"7":{"0":"188230.86"},"8":{"0":"80646.05"},"9":{"0":"11352.48"},"10":{"0":"4461.90"}}

Can anyone help me to bring this down to something like this

> {34954.68,20544.20,102702.76 ... 4461.90}

Many thanks.

Comment: replace ` $amount[] = $temp;` for  `$amount[] = floatval($temp[1]);`

Comment: what you get exactly in $xml->RECORD,, give the out put then it is to parse data to form JSON ,like this (ex)echo json_encode(array("name"=>"demo","time"=>"8pm"));

Comment: @SamArulRaj I got the pattern, that's why I am stumped on how to bypass that.

Comment: @MrA good work  ,,i agree with Rob

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` if you're trying to get a simple array. Try something like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.XML");
$amount = array();
$temp = 0;

echo $xml->getName() . "</br>";

foreach ($xml->RECORD as $first_gen) {
    foreach ($first_gen->Inventory_Value_at_Cost as $second_gen){
        $temp = $second_gen;
        $amount[] = array_values($temp);
    }
}
echo json_encode($amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the whole array which is returned in $second_gen replace the following code:

```
...
$temp = $second_gen;
$amount[] = $temp;
...
```

with:

```
...
$amount[] = $second_gen[0];
...
```

Comment: It was able to remove it but ... [{"0":"34954.68"},{"0":"20544.20"},{"0":"102702.76"},{"0":"89018.95"},{"0":"42479.36"},{"0":"58479.60"},{"0":"47609.10"},{"0":"188230.86"},{"0":"80646.05"},{"0":"11352.48"},{"0":"4461.90"}] ... how can I remove the last "0"s further?

Comment: As Rob said before, remove also JSON_FORCE_OBJECT in json_encode, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rob is correct, take off the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

try:

```
$amount[] = $second_gen[0]
```

and

```
echo json_encode($amount);
```